# is it possible to add image into actionbar tab?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an actionbar with four tabs. Is there anyway to add image onto the tab?

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Books").setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Lab coat").setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tools").setTabListener(this));       
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Others").setTabListener(this));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

Checkout this link [ActionBar.Tab.setIcon(Drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)
Sample code

```
tab = getActionBar.newTab();
tab.setText(tabText);
tab.setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Please see the awesome library [ViewPageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/) from jake warton and follow the IconPageIndicator example. Which will solve your problem

Comment: +1 It's a great library with a sample solution to this problem.